# What does pwd_leak mean in the Auth0 user login logs

Tags: android, auth0

I have used Auth0 for authentication and to get token for user. I've then created a test user using the Auth0 dashboard.

When I try to login with my Android app, it logins successfully, but in the logs I got records like `Success Login` and after that `pwd_leak`.

Can somebody explain what this `pwd_leak` stands for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auth0 provides built-in tools to detect anomalies and stop malicious attempts to access your application. This is known as [anomaly detection](https://auth0.com/docs/anomaly-detection).

One of it's features is the detection of the usage of credentials that have been leaked publicly. See the [Breached Password Detection](https://auth0.com/docs/anomaly-detection#breached-password-detection) section for more information, but very simplified is that if user tries to login with identical email/password combination to ones that have been publicly leaked then Auth0 can be configured to notify or block those attempts.

The `pwd_leak` indication on the logs will likely mean that the associated credentials were part of a public leak. The [';--have i been pwned?](https://haveibeenpwned.com/) application might be of interest because it's also another place that tracks known password leaks and a good way to check if you might have been compromised.